# Domain name question

Tags: domain-registration

So I set up my business email via g suite which created the domain name via godaddy. I have heard bad reviews on godaddy and was looking at a different host for my website. Do I have to host on godaddy since that is where I bought the domain from?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

No you can host anywhere. Godaddy can just be your domain registrar, and you can update your domain to point to any other host.